# How to send multiple objects with same state to a method with single Object parameter using Java?

Tags: java, javabeans, static-methods

**Java Version : 1.6**

I have multiple beans with similar structure

```
ClassBean1 {
   String firstName;
   String middleName;
   String lastName;
}



UtilClass {

   public static void concatName(ClassBean1 object) {
        String fullName =  object.firstName + object.middleName + object.lastName;
        System.out.println(fullName); 
   }

}

Mainclass {
   UtilClass.concatName(newClassBean1)
}
```

Now I get one more bean class with same structure as of ClassBean1; Say ClassBean2

```
ClassBean2 {
   String firstName;
   String middleName;
   String lastName;
}
```

I want to modify  UtilClass.concatName such that it works on all object with firstName, middleName & lastName. I have done following changes:

```
UtilClass {

   public static void concatName(Object object) {
        String fullName =  object.firstName + object.middleName + object.lastName;
        System.out.println(fullName); 
   }

}
```

But it gives compile time errors. **Could anyone please help in resolving!!!**

I could not touch existing bean i.e ClassBean1. So the new code i can take care off creating base class and derived fundaa; but refactor it so that existing code should work

Comment: What are those compile time errors? (ALso, if you have a common interface why not use a, erm, common `Interface`?)

Comment: "What are those compile time errors?" @doctorlove ... I guess it will have to do with Object not having a field called "firstName" and so on ...

Comment: @doctorlove:

it says cannot find firstname, lastname middle name

Comment: @Fildor I was hoping to comment would inspire a "D'oh" moment...

Comment: @doctorlove ooops. I spoilt it, sorry! But I guess the "D'oh" won't come anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a base class with the members and method that you want to derive all your other classes from, in your base class define the name members and the concatName method, then every object derived from this will inherit the members and function and it will work.

Comment: Thanks. BUt If you forget about base class and concentrate on UtilClass then how can we modify UtilClass method to take any kind of object having same state

Comment: you have to check the state when calling the method

Comment: All you need to do is make your function take a instance of the base class then all objects that call it derived from the base will work - polymorphism

Comment: Thanks for that. Any other way instead of comparing instance i mean i want to change parameter only and it should be done.

Comment: The method can be anywhere as long as all the objects that have the name use the same name class.

Comment: @SPlatten: 

BUt it gives compile time error. It says "cannot find symbol".
At runtime maybe it can detect the class!! but compile time in netbeans is bit

Comment: @fatherazrel, What symbol?

Comment: LIke if we have methods in ClassBean1 which is same ass ClassBean2. It says Cannot find symbol that method name. Such kind of error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115947/discussion-between-fatherazrael-and-splatten).

Comment: @fatherazrael If your Util method takes an Object, then only the methods/fields of Object are visible. Doesn't matter if the actual type is ClassBean1 or Integer or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Create a parent class with those three variables, inherit other classes which will use those 3 from that parent class than:

```
public static void concatName(Parent object) {
    String fullName =  object.firstName + object.middleName + object.lastName;
    System.out.println(fullName);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

And if you REALLY want to do it without createing the base class, the only way I can come up with is reflection. That awy, you can have an Object as the method param. Then, in your method, you can use reflection to see if all the required methods are there and call them to get the data.

But this is very ugly and should not be attempted. The best way would be either a base class or a common interface, as suggested before.

Comment: can you give me a snippet for same? 

As i do not want to use Object and then instance of. I could not make base class; so that is out of scope for me.

Comment: Well, an as evenly ugly "instanceof" and casting may also work. If you consider this reflection, then nevermind.

Comment: But i cant use instanceOf and casting suppose there are 10 objects having same fields. (AN I CANNOT CHANGE ANY OF THEM) and i am making 11th one and refactoring existing UTIL class. then how can i do so that all those 10 objects also work and my object also work.

Comment: @fatherazrael You cannot. The design is broken. All your patching around makes it worse. You need to get someone in charge to fix this **design flaw**.

Answer (score 1):

You can check using `instanceof`

```
public static void concatName(Object object) {

      if(object instanceof ClassBean1){
            ClassBean1 b1 = (ClassBean1) object;
            String fullName = b1.firstName +b1.middleName + b1.lastName;
            System.out.println(fullName);
      } else if(object instanceof ClassBean2){
            ClassBean2 b2 = (ClassBean2) object;
            String fullName = b2.firstName +b2.middleName + b2.lastName;
            System.out.println(fullName);
      }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to get the class fields/variables.

Pass the bean of any type having common state i.e the common variables you want to use in the UtilClass function and use the very base class of each object that is Object class as a parameter for the same method. Now  extract the class object from that variable and  used reflection methods to get the variables values.

```
public static void concatName(Object object) {

    // 
    Class clazz = object.getClass();

    String fullName = null;
    try {
        fullName =  clazz.getDeclaredField("firstName").get(object) +" "+ clazz.getDeclaredField("middleName").get(object) + " " +clazz.getDeclaredField("lastName").get(object);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException
            | NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {
    }

    System.out.println(fullName);


}
```

With this approach you can get the required result without polymorphism/inheritance or altering the bean classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a method in Util class, which will take three parameter and call that method from main class.

UtilClass {

public static void concatName(String firstName, String middleName, String lastName) {
        String fullName = firstName + middleName + lastName;
        System.out.println(fullName); 
   }

}

Mainclass {
   UtilClass.concatName(newClassBean1.getFirstName() + newClassBean1.getMiddleName() + newClassBean1.getLastName())
//for second class
 UtilClass.concatName(newClassBean2.getFirstName() + newClassBean2.getMiddleName() + newClassBean2.getLastName())
}